# docker: invalide reference format

Tags: php, docker, apache

i'm following a php tutorial that uses Docker, so when i want to load apache image it shows an error "docker: "invalid reference format"
and this is the command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-apache-php-app -v C:\Users\INFO PC\Desktop\phpdockertuto:/var/www/html php:7.2-apache
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Quote the path.

Comment: Your INFO PC folder is causing the problem, there cannot be a blank space, messes up the format.

Comment: thank you you are right, it's INFO PC folder causing the problem